# Limit of 2 circles

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

Let $S$ be a circle, centre $(3,0)$, and with a radius of $3$, and $R$ which has a radius in $(0,0)$ and a radius of $r>0$. Let $A$ be the intersection of circles $S$ and $R$, and $B$ intersection of circle $R$ and line $x=0$. Let $l$ be a line going across $A$ and $B$ and $C$ is a point where $l$ crosses $x$ -axis. What is the limit of $x$ coordinate of $C$ when $r \to 0^+$.

I drew a little picture, but can not get grasp of the calculations of this

Comment: $S$ and $R$ (usually) intersect in _two_ points, Which of them is $A$? $R$ and $x = 0$ intersect in two points, which of them is $B$?

Comment: The setup is unclear. If you want answers, I suggest you add a diagram using GeoGebra or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I presume points $A$ and $B$ to have both $y>0$ (you forgot to mention a criterion to pick the right points). Let $O=(0,0)$ and $K=(3,0)$ be the circle centers, and $\angle AOB=\alpha$. Then $\angle ACO=\alpha/2$ and $\angle AKO=2\alpha$, so that
$$
OC={AO\cos(\alpha/2)\over\tan(\alpha/2)}
\quad\hbox{and}\quad
AO=6\sin\alpha,
\quad\hbox{whence}\quad
OC=12\cos^3(\alpha/2).
$$
Now it is easy to compute the limit for $AO\to0$, that is for $\alpha\to0$.

[image]